# Android how to convert an exsting dump db in other one with FTS support?

Tags: android, sqlite, sd-card, fts3

I have a .db sqlite file that I can import form sdcard. How can I add FTS support? I must recreate all table? Please give some tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to create any FTS tables for the data you want to search. For example, if you have a Customer table and a Products table, you would need to create both a CustomerFTS table and a Products FTS table.

After those tables are created, you then have to insert the data you wish to search into those tables. You can either look at the example of FTS support in http://blog.andresteingress.com/2011/09/30/android-quick-tip-using-sqlite-fts-tables/

or from the Android Developer site  http://developer.android.com/training/search/search.html  Where they show how to create a table and populate it with data.